# getApplicationEnabledSetting(pkgName) got NullPointException error

Tags: android, android-package-managers

When I use these Method In Intellij IDE(`Android Studio`), I got these info:
Method invocation `mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationEnabledSetting(pkgName)` may produce `java.lang.NullPointerException` less... (`Ctrl+F1`) 
This inspection reports those conditions in the specified inspection scope that are always true or false, as well as points out where a RuntimeException may be thrown, based on data flow analysis of the code. This inspection also reports Nullable/NotNull contract violations. Annotations to support the contract can be configured (by default @Nullable/@NotNull annotations from annotations.jar will be used)

But only IllegalArgumentException describled in [dev api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationEnabledSetting%28java.lang.String%29)

The question is: **What condition that I will get NULLPOINTEXCEPTION?**

I got a simple test Example app,Just use thes method on create()

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         int testint= this.getPackageManager().getApplicationEnabledSetting("com.android.mms");//NullPointException
    }
```

Unfortune NullPointException happended. The packageName is Message App,not original
google's app,modified.
Thanks

Comment: The null is referred to mContext.getPackageManager()

Comment: NO,I am sure is getApplicationEnabledSetting(String packagename)

Comment: PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
                                                                             int temp = pm.getApplicationEnabledSetting(pkgName);//message got here,pkgname is also sure not null

Comment: pm may be null, so pm.get....will throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

`mContext` maybe `null` and thus `mContext.getPackageManager()` may throw a NPE.